# Sending XML file to activemq

Tags: xml, xslt, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I currently have a camel route set up to take something from an activemq topic, pass it through a .xsl to transform it and then pass it to another activemq topic. My only problem right now is I am not exactly sure how to actually go about posting an xml file to the queue in the first place for this whole process to start.

I thought about sending the whole thing in just a string but I wasn't sure if that would get picked up by the xsl file to transform it. If anyone has any tips or ways of sending xml files to an activemq queue or topic your help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1)
ActiveMQ comes with a web console, where you can send messages to a queue or topic.
This console is by default available on

```
http://localhost:8161/admin
```

There is a WebConsole readme file in the ActiveMQ distribution that gives your further details.

2)
You can also send a message from JConsole (eg JMX).

3)
And alternative is to use a Camel route, that consume from a file directory and send to the topic. Then you can drop the file in the directory and let Camel pickup and send the file.

```
<route>
  <from uri="file:somedir/inbox"/>
  <to uri="activemq:topic:someTopicName"/>
</route>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please refer the below code.
    Here we will receive message simple file creation then writing bytes coming from BytesMessageObject until EOF occurs.
                BytesMessage bm = (BytesMessage)topicSubscriber.receiveNoWait(); // receive(1000);
                    System.out.println("bm-->"+bm);
                    if(bm !=null){
                     File file = new File("D:/jms/myfie.txt"); //file created
                     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);//create fileoutput stream
                     BufferedOutputStream outBuf = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);//create bufferoutputstream
                     int i;
                     while((i=bm.readInt())!=-1)//read unitil EOF means -1
    {
                        outBuf.write(i);//write it to the file
                     }
                     System.out.println("outBuf-->"+outBuf);
                     System.out.println(file.isFile());
                     outBuf.close();//close output buffer
                     fos.close();//close file ouput stream
                    }

    Here the file is opened then
    Wrote in BytesMessageObject.
    Sent Across the Queue            

                Sender code :

                File f=new File("D:/Import.txt");//get  file handle
                          System.out.println("is File "+f.isFile());
                          BytesMessage bm = topicSession.createBytesMessage();//create bytes message
                          InputStream in= new FileInputStream(f);//create input stream with file handle
                          BufferedInputStream inBuf= new BufferedInputStream(in);//create buffer input stream
                          int i;
                          while((i=inBuf.read())!=-1)//read file until EOF(-1)  is reached{
                             bm.writeInt(i);//write in bytesmessage
                          }
                          System.out.println("after while");
                          //adding an eof
                          bm.writeInt(-1);//add EOF in bytes message
                          System.out.println("BM = "+bm);
                          topicPublisher.send(bm);///send the bytes message
                          System.out.println("sent successfully");
                          topicConnection.stop();//stop connection
```

Comment: Please don't just dump some code. Explain how your code actually *solves* the problem in the question.

Comment: @ekad is it fine now answer explanation